# Android Add Button on WebView?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I add a button on a `WebView`?. I have a WebView and I want to show a popup. For that I need to add a button on the bottom-left corner of WebVew. How can I do this?

Comment: do you mean to add button inside WebView or bottom-left corner of it?

Comment: Inside the webview, and it position at bottom-left corner.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use a [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative). I like using it a lot. Its a great way to easily place and organize views,buttons,layouts,etc...

> Some Example code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFD0">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/My_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="My Button!" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I think the views and buttons will be drawn in order from top to bottom in the **XML**, but it may be the other way around.use margins like :

`android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"` and  `android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"`
 
to help **adjust the position**.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of content is in the `WebView`? Is it some HTML that you can control / modify?

- If yes, just add a `<button>` tag and position it accordingly using CSS.
- If no, use Wayner's solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class webview extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);

        Button btnTag = new Button(this);
        btnTag.setText("Button");
        btnTag.setId(1);
        webview.addView(btnTag);
        setContentView(webview);

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        final Activity activity = this;
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
            }
        });

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {

                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");

    }

}
```